# Errors while viewshed analysis in QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, viewshed

I want to analyze viewshed from some point. For that, I installed the viewshed plugin, and run it.

elevation raster: dem
observation points: observer(only one point)

But it just shows the message `"One object selected in the layer observer."`, left bottom of QGIS window.

And there is no error message and no result file.

And the observer layer really was selected one point.

[image: Example]

Comment: As an alternative you can use GRASS gis r.viewshed. I see it to the right in your screenshot

Comment: Please share with us your data. I just tried selecting one feature, changing crs and other things and it works always. Just brakes when you try the viewshed to a very long distance or with a very high resolution DEM.

Comment: thank you. maybe high resolution DEM is problem maker...^^